# Postman: how to get count of number string value from response

Tags: postman

I want to get the count of string `name` from the response, ex: here my count in 2

```
[
    {
        "name": One,
        "next": null,
    } 
    {
        "name": Two,
        "next": null,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's your response data, you could use:

`console.log(_.filter(pm.response.json(), 'name').length)`

This would console log out the number of `keys` that are called `name`.

Comment: That seems like another question. If you accept this as an answer and create a new one with the details of what you're having a problem with, me or other people can help you.